# Is there a source for owning property in Israel means keeping 1 day yom tov

Tags: eretz-yisrael, yom-tov, real-estate

People have said, and I have seen [mentioned on this site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7000/becoming-bnei-eretz-yisroel-on-yom-tov/11080) that owning land/property/apartment in Israel is enough on its own to keep 1 day when in Israel.  Is there a source for this?  A shita that the only criteria to be considered Israeli for 1 day is owning land?

The case would be someone living outside of Israel, has no intention of living in Israel, and comes lets say for 10-15 days a year to Israel.  They are in Israel at least one chag, but no more than 2 a year.  And they own an apartment.  Is there a source that this guy would keep 1 day because he owns an apartment?  Exclude all the opinions that hold that he would keep 1 day even if he did not own an apartment.

I know Rav Auerbach requires an apartment but that is in addition to being in Israel for all 3 festivals every year.  [Halachapedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Second_Day_of_Yom_Tov#cite_ref-35)  says

> If someone owns an apartment in Israel .... Some however hold that one should keep one day.

But the note links that to making full time aliya.  However I could not find any reference to it in the source material.

Comment: Do you mean "property" or a "residence"? You could own a portion of an abandoned field in the middle of nowhere but not live there (sounds crazy but I know someone who had that situation)

Comment: @DoubleAA or even better you could own a portion of a field such as https://www.adama613.com and perform many land-dependent mitzvot (note I have no connection with them)

Comment: DoubleAA, @mbloch, or you could own a tiny bit of land because you owed an Israeli money before _sh'mita_ and he gave you land so he could write a _p'ruzbul_.

Comment: @ Double-aa Yes I would like to see your source for owning an abandoned field and keeping one day.  I do not think I was prejudicial to any case. I am just trying to find whats out there.  I said owning land/property/apartment in the question. Im not sure why you would think that your case would not be included. Can you reveal your source please?

Answer (score 6):

R Eliezer Melamed ([Peninei Halacha Moadim 9:8](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/12-09-08/)) writes indeed

> **If one buys an apartment in Eretz Yisrael and lives there during his
> visits, he is considered a resident of Eretz Yisrael while there.**

R Melamed doesn't cite primary sources although he is, on his own, a well-respected and mainstream *posek* in Israel. His Peninei Halacha has become a standard text for *halacha lema'ase*.

I found [one opinion](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/6007) that explicitly disagrees with the above, in your specific case.

For a good summary of sources on your question (although it doesn’t address your exact case) see [here](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/yom-tov-sheni-2)

Comment: Thanks for the source.  I would not translate the English that way, but he does say it and gives no source or reason.  Some of his other reasons to keep one day would correlate with reasons that sefardim hold of but not Ashkenazi.  Would you say he is a Sefardi posek, or his pesak would also apply generally to Ashkenaz?

Comment: He is not a sefardi posek although is community has Ashkenazim, Sefaradim, Teimanim, etc. But he is definitely an Ashkenazi posek. This being said, please don't rely on what you read on this site. Ask your Rav, and maybe share with him the sources you learned about here. Alternatively you can contact R Melamed through https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/about/ and ask about your specific case

Comment: My asking a question excludes me from being a Rav?  I guess that's what's wrong with the world